# Problem passing string value into animate Jquery function

Tags: jquery, string, variables, jquery-animate, assign

Hey I'm wonder what's the difference between these 2 codes? The first works but the 2nd doesnt?

```
First >>
for (i=0; i<$sequencingArray.length; i++){
...
$($sequencingArray[i]).delay(i*100).animate({'margin-left':$masterWidth});
...
}

Second >>
$propToAnimate = 'margin-left';
for (i=0; i<$sequencingArray.length; i++){
...
$($sequencingArray[i]).delay(i*100).animate({$propToAnimate:$masterWidth});
...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a working solution...

```
$propToAnimate = {'margin-left': $masterWidth};
$($sequencingArray[i]).delay(i*100).animate($propToAnimate);
```

"You cannot use a variable as a property name inside an object literal." [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/javascript-jquery-using-a-variable-in-the-css-property-of-animate)

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `{'margin-left':$masterWidth}` or `{$propToAnimate:$masterWidth}`you are creating an object.  So we need to know what we are doing when we create an object using the [Object Initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_Object_Initializers) (`{k0:v0, k1:v1}`) syntax.

Most importantly for your case `var a = {prop:20}` and `var a = {'prop':20}` will both do exactly the same thing -- create an object with one property called `prop`. It doesn't matter if you had already said `var prop = 'different'` elsewhere, `prop` is just treated as a literal name when used in `{prop:20}` and is not evaluated.

What you could do to make the second version of your code work, is make use of the `a['prop']` syntax for objects.  So something like:

```
var prop = 'margin-left';
var obj = {}; // Create a new object with no propeties
obj[prop] = masterWidth; // Add a new property to obj (using the value of the variable prop as the name of the new property)
```

Then you will have `obj['margin-left'] == masterWidth`.  And you can use this object in the animate function... `animate(obj);`

I hope I haven't been too confusing!